# How to scale a numpy array from 0 to 1 with overshoot?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, normalize

I am trying to scale a pandas or numpy array from 0 to a unknown max value with the defined number replaced with 1.

One solution I tried is just dividing the defined number I want by the array.

```
test = df['Temp'] / 33
```

[image: plot]

This method does not scale all the way from 0 and I'm stuck trying to figure out a better mathematical way of solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, transform the DataFrame to a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
T = np.array(df['Temp'])
```

Then scale it to a [0, 1] interval:

```
def scale(A):
    return (A-np.min(A))/(np.max(A) - np.min(A))

T_scaled = scale(T)
```

Then transform it to anywhere you want, e.g. to [55..100]

```
T2 = 55 + 45*T_scaled
```

I'm sure that this can be done within Pandas too (but I'm not familiar with it). Perhaps you might study Pandas `df.apply()`

Answer (score 1):

```
scaled = (df['Temp']-df['Temp'].min()) / (33 - df['Temp'].min())
```

Just replace **33** with the number to want your data scaled to!

[image: Original]
[image: Scaled]